# Command using either or both -Path parameter and $input?

Tags: powershell

I would like to write a PowerShell script that will accept a list of files to process or be able to take its input from stdin. The command will take in text and produce piglatin. (You're right, I am actually doing something else, but this is the scenario.)

```
Edit-PigLatin -Path 'story.txt'
    or
Get-Content -Path 'story.txt' | Edit-PigLatin
```

I want to make the -Path parameter not mandatory.

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage='input filename')]
[string[]]$Path
```

I have not been able to find a solution that will use either or both -Path parameters and $input. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

An obvious problem I see here is that you are passing in the name of a file in the 1st case and the in 2nd, you are passing in the content of the file. If you send it both to the same variable, you are going to have a problem inside your script.

Might I suggest an alternative approach:

```
function Edit-Piglatin
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, 
        ValueFromPipeline=$true,
        Position=0)]
        [string[]]$Content,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, 
        ValueFromPipeline=$false,
        Position=1)]
        [string[]]$Path
    )

    #named parameter $path will get the input for the filename
    #values from pipeline will go to automatically go to $content 

    if ($Path)
    {
        #use this as input
    }
    elseif ($Content)
    {
        #use this as input
    }
    else
    {
        #no input
    }
}
```

The trick is in this `ValueFromPipeline=$true`, together with `Position=0`. Now with a simple `if-else` condition, you can determine which variable to process inside your function.